# Is there a way to use shell (esp Bash) conditionals to check exact file mode like [[ -mode 0755 ]]

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have an activity setup, and I want a certain file to always have an exact file mode defined by:

```
chmod 0671 someoldfile.something
```

I know I could just always chmod it to get that, but it would be less intrusive to just test to make sure it has mode 0671.  I was hoping there would be some test like:

```
if [[ -mode 0671 ]]
then
   echo "I am so happy."
else
   echo "I am so sad."
fi
```

Sorry if this should be obvious, but I did look around, and I am not a shell newbie, so I know this isn't something everyone just knows.

I've googled, but it always just brings up how to use chmod.

See 1 above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `[[` or `test` directly, but you can use `find`:

```
if [ "$(find "someoldfile.something" -perm 0671)" ]
then
  echo "The mode is exactly 0671"
fi
```

This is POSIX compatible.

Comment: Of course.  Good idea.  I also just found I can do something like this:

Comment: I also just found I can do something like this:  if [[ $(stat -c "%a" psmons.bashenv) = "664" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi

Comment: @user3713271 notice that `stat(1)` is not portable; it has a completely different syntax on MacOS, FreeBSD, etc and it doesn't exist at all on some systems.

Comment: @thatotherguy ok, got it